# Google sheet doesn't recognize dates

Tags: google-sheets

In the below sheet Column A represents Date. But some dates not recognized by google sheets. For example from cell A5 to A51 not recognized. I copied Column A to Column G and changed the date format of Column G to DD-MM-YYYY. Also,  I changed the time zone from US to India. But still problem not solved. I tried "Date" formula in H2. It also failed. I need the date in the exact format DD-MM-YYYY in Column J. Please find a solution. PFA

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kej4tP6pofeOSU9flhICVR7owIYwNHnTaoNbLuO8WBs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a date format where `02-01-2022` means 2 January 2022 rather than 1 February 2022. When you directly enter that value in a spreadsheet whose locale assumes the `m/d/yyyy` date format, the value gets interpreted as `02/01/2022`, i.e., 1 February 2022, the opposite of what you want.

There are only 12 months in a year, and most of your values start with a number that is greater than that. As a result, most of the values in column `A` are not numeric dates but text strings that just look like dates. The rest of the values have been interpreted as dates but have their day and month reversed.

The silver lining is that the data appears to have been entered in the same invalid format throughout. This means that the data can be fixed, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    len(A2:A), 
    to_date( value( 
      regexreplace(to_text(A2:A), "(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)", "$3-$2-$1") 
    ) ), 
    iferror(ø) 
  ) 
)
```

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kej4tP6pofeOSU9flhICVR7owIYwNHnTaoNbLuO8WBs/edit#gid=423309510) sheet in your sample spreadsheet. The formula is in cell `G1`. You can overwrite your original data with these corrected values using **Edit > Paste special > Paste values only**.

To best avoid confusion whether `12/1` means 1st of December (month/day) or 12 January (day/month), make sure that **File > Settings > Locale** matches your real locale. The default locale is set based on your Google Account details.

One very good strategy is to use the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date format `yyyy-MM-dd` consistently everywhere. It works in any locale.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153275/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

The formula uses `if()` and will thus return dateserial values that need to be formatted as dates to be readable through **Format > Number > Date** or a custom date format of your choosing. You can avoid that by using a closed-end range such as `A2:A120` and removing the `if()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  to_date( value( 
    regexreplace(to_text(A2:A120), "(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)", "$3-$2-$1") 
  ) ) 
)
```

That will give dates in the default date format of the spreadsheet. To set another date format directly in the formula, use this pattern:

```
=let( 
  format_, lambda(v,f,map({v},lambda(v,query(v,"format Col1'"&f&"'", 0)))), 

  fixed, arrayformula( 
    if( 
      len(A2:A), 
      to_date( value( 
        regexreplace(to_text(A2:A), "(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)", "$3-$2-$1") 
      ) ), 
      iferror(ø) 
    ) 
  ), 
  
  format_(fixed, "dd-MM-yyyy") 
)
```